# Heroku App not displaying same positioning/css as localhost

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, heroku, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with my locally hosted site having correct CSS/positioning but after it is deployed to Heroku it seems to lose some CSS. I am running mostly MERN Stack. I suspect it is going to be a problem relating to my node_modules but I have them in my git ignore and am not very knowledgable in that area. The best example I have is my About Us page. I've never encountered this issue and have found only info about Rails projects having this issue. I have tried uninstalling/re-installing bootstrap and added the CDN to the index.js file. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Deployed Site Screen Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdjKi.png)

[Locally Hosted Screen Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De8R5.png)

[Updated Deployed Site Screen Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbtNi.png)

[Updated Locally Hosted Screen Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wff6N.png)

UPDATE:
Found this CSS library is very helpful and helped fix my wonky CSS in production.
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Try clearing your cache?

Comment: Just tried that and the issue persists

Comment: Questions that are just a bit more than a link to a website are off-topic here. The reason is that when a link gets obsolete, the question is no longer useful to future readers. We are trying to build a lasting repository of useful 

question/answer pairs 

here. Please read 
[**Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) 
as well as how to use this site in general
[**taking the tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful comment. I'll make sure to remove the links and leave only code and pictures then.

Answer (score 0):

It may be you cache problem.

it can be a problem because of VH (Viewport Height) property. and it will be change according to screen height.

- Viewport = the browser window size. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw = 0.5cm.

i just saw your code and seems you are using static height for `.about-wrapper`.

i your case you should remove height property for `.about-wrapper` selector.

Comment: I removed the height from .about-wrapper but it doesn't seem like anything really changed

Comment: and you are using  margin-top: 7vh for .logo.

vh will vary according to screen height

Comment: and you are using  margin-top: 7vh for .logo.

vh will vary according to screen height.

according to your requirement, you should use pixel instead of vh.

Comment: I fixed that as well and update the images. My main question is why my spacing and my CSS is different in production vs development/localhost. This area is not the only area affected.